# jQuery hover function to slide span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have created some share buttons in an attempt to make the standard like, tweet, pin etc look a bit nicer. I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgxZB/) to demonstrate the problem I'm having. They almost work as intended but on hover I need the span to stay out of the way to allow the user to click on the button underneath and cannot figure it out. If you play with the fiddle you will see what I mean.

**My html:**

```
<div class="sharebuttons">
    <ul>
        <li id="tweet"><span></span><a href="">tweet</a></li>
        <li id="like"><span></span><a href="">like</a></li>
        <li id="pin"><span></span><a href="">pin</a></li>
        <li id="plusone"><span></span><a href="">plusone</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sharebuttons ul li span').hover(function(){
        $(this).slideUp();
    }, function(){
        $(this).slideDown();
    });
});
```

The working fiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/bgxZB/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target the hover on `li` instead of `span`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sharebuttons ul li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('span').slideUp();
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('span').slideDown();
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bgxZB/1/)**